# Sharing Asp.Net MVC url with facebook

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, model-view-controller

I have a page inside my website displaying post details. The url looks like: mydomain/review/reviewdetails/id

NB: Here id is the mvc parameter and it is going to be changed dynamically for each post.

Now the problem is, when i'm creating a new post a new id is generating and the url for the new id is separate from the previous url due to the id has changed. So, I need to debug the url using facebook debugger to get the correct image and description for the post while sharing.

I'm stuck. Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? Not really clear what the actual _question_ is supposed to be here. Please go read [ask].

Comment: Please follow the below links:
mydomain/review/reviewdetails/2
mydomain/review/reviewdetails/3

For both of the link I need to use facebook debugger to collect actual title, image and description while sharing though both of them are from a single page.

Am I clear?

Comment: _“though both of them are from a single page”_ - these are two different URLs, and as such they are considered two different Open Graph objects. “Single page” doesn’t mean anything in that regard. If getting the data on first share doesn’t work most of the time, it usually means your server is too slow to respond. Workaround would be to automatically trigger a scrape via API (research it) when you publish a new URL.

Answer (score 0):

**Full Code Example**

> Copy & paste the code example to your website. Adjust the value
>   data-href to your website URL. Next use the og:*** meta tags to adjust
>   your link preview. og:url and data-href should use the same URL.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Your Website Title</title>
    <!-- You can use Open Graph tags to customize link previews.
    Learn more: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters -->
  <meta property="og:url"           content="https://www.your-domain.com/your-page.html" />
  <meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
  <meta property="og:title"         content="Your Website Title" />
  <meta property="og:description"   content="Your description" />
  <meta property="og:image"         content="https://www.your-domain.com/path/image.jpg" />
</head>
<body>

  <!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.0";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

  <!-- Your share button code -->
  <div class="fb-share-button" 
    data-href="https://www.your-domain.com/your-page.html" 
    data-layout="button_count">
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Phillips,

Thanks for your answer and this is appreciable. 

Actually I did all this before and the fact is when my link changed to mydomain/postdetails/13 to mydomain/postdetails/14 then the image is not showing up until I debug for the new url.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the solution below:

*** TESTCONTROLLER

```
public ActionResult TestId(int? id)
{
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        News news = db.News.Find(id);
        if (news == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(news);
    }
```

*** VIEW

```
@{
     string @url = "http://YOUR_URL/TEST/TestID/" + Html.DisplayFor(model => model.IdNews);
    string @fb_shared_page = "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2f%2fYOUR_URL%2fTEST%2fTestId2f" + Html.DisplayFor(model => model.IdNews) + "&amp; src = sdkpreparse";
}

<div class="fb-share-button" data-href=" @url" data-layout="button" data-size="small">
   <a target="_blank" href="@fb_shared_page" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
      Shared
   </a>
 </div>
```

Note:

- TEST is your Controller
- TestId is your function on your TESTController which has an id parameter as integer
- IdNews is your Id retrieve from your database table name News (See db.News Controller)